# How to fix text encoding in python

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have some text which is not in proper UTF-8 encoding. So when BERT tokenizer tokenize it, it failed.
Here is example

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
s =" ае ое  '  ? \n⚡️   ! \n⚡️       ! \n       ,         .      ."
model_name = "bert-base-multilingual-cased"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
print(tokenizer.tokenize(s))
```

Output

```
['[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', "'", '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '?', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '!', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '!', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', ',', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '.', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '[UNK]', '.']
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly proper UTF-8 encoding.  The problem is, those are not ASCII characters.  Those are mathematical symbols and Cyrillic characters that happen to be shaped like English letters.  The first character is U+1D5DC.  To BERT, it looks like Chinese.

Since I assume these are from spam, I'm not sure how much trouble you want to go to.  Python does have a built-in module to translate English-like letters to English:

```
import unicodedata
s=" ае ое  '  ? \n⚡️   "

s1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',s)
print(s1)
```

Output:

```
Is passive income what you're looking for? 
⚡️Investment platform for beg
```

Comment: It will be necessary to first normalise to NFKC or NFKD as desired, then transliterate Cyrillic to Latin, and potentially strip out the emoji in the string.